# Can't figure out why form.has_changed() is always true?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to learn Django and have come up with a situation I can't figure out. I have the following code:

```
def contact_add(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactManageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.has_changed(): # <-- ALWAYS RETURNS TRUE!
            form.clean()
            ...

elif 'id' in request.GET:  # Request to show an existing contact
    new_contact_dynamic = contacts.models.PersonDynamic.objects.get(person_static = request.GET['id'],
                                                                    current_record_fg = True)
    form = ContactManageForm(new_contact_dynamic.__dict__, initial=new_contact_dynamic.__dict__)

else:  # This must be to add a new contact
    form = ContactAddForm()

return render(request, 'contact_manage.html', {'form': form})
```

So, if I'm sent an ID number, I read a record and display it on the screen. My template gives the user a 'submit changes' button. My problem, as noted above, is that Django always shows that the form has changed, even if the user hasn't changed any data on the screen (i.e. he just hit the submit changes button without changing anything).

So, am I doing something obviously wrong in my code that's creating this situation? Am I misinterpreting how the form.has_changed() method works?

It's my assumption that when I use the `initial=`parameter after a GET request, Django is storing that data somewhere and knows the context when the user then hits the 'submit data' button, is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is wrong. Django compares the form data to the initial data, but since you don't pass in any initial data in the POST request, it will always say the data changed. You need to pass in the same initial data in the POST request.

Comment: @knbk Thanks for that! Does that mean that I must requery my DB to get the initial data that I populated the form with (see the GET handling?) or is that saved somewhere? If I need to query the DB again, how do I get the original person_static_id? Do I read the request.POST first and get it from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to initialize your Form with `initial` data.
In your view the GET and POST requests have no common context. You may want to use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/) for that.

But in this case, it is not necessary. You can retrieve the instance on each request:

```
def contact_add(request):
    if 'id' in request.GET:
        new_contact_dynamic = contacts.models.PersonDynamic.objects.get(
            person_static = request.GET['id'],
            current_record_fg = True
        )
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactManageForm(request.POST, initial=new_contact_dynamic.__dict__)
            ...
        else: # Show an existing contact
            form = ContactManageForm(initial=new_contact_dynamic.__dict__)
    else:
        form = ContactAddForm()

    return render(request, 'contact_manage.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you, Adrien, this helps. It seems that Django is, in ways, similar to writing any other Restful system - each interaction is independent of the others and parameters get passed around to give context to them. Thanks again!